# Custom rewrite permalinks WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have a page template that gets some variables added to the end of the url so I can display data based on what was passed.

ie: mysite.com/search-listins/listing/?address=123+The+Street&mls-number=00000

I need to convert this into a pretty permalink. Somthing like this:

mysite.com/search-listings/listing/123-The-Street OR mysite.com/search-listings/listing/00000-123-The-Street

I tried using this function. But nothing seems to be working. Any thoughts? These are not coming from a custom post type. As you can see, these are not a custom post type. These are MLS items that live outside the wp_ tables.

Function:

```
 function setup_filter_rewrites(){
     add_rewrite_rule('search-listings/listing/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=search-     listings/listing/?address=$matches[1]&mls-number=$matches[2]', 'top');
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );

 function setup_filter_query_vars( $query_vars ){
     $query_vars[] = 'listing';
     return $query_vars;
 }
 add_filter( 'query_vars', 'setup_filter_query_vars' );`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using this code instead of add_rewrite_rule() function:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function dlouhavidea_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'address';
    $vars[] = 'miles';    
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function ,y_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'search-listings/listing/address/?([^/]*)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?pagename=search-listings&address=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        'search-listings/listing/miles/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?pagename=search-listings&miles=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 )       
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

You'll than find your vars in get_query_var('address') and get_query_var('miles');